# wc -l file to a variable

Tags: shell

Given a filepath, I would like to find out how many lines there are and store them into a variable. For example:

```
/three_little_pigs.csv

straw
wood
bricks
```

In a file, I would like to have the number (or string `3`) stored. Tried the following commands:

```
export P="three_little_pigs.csv"
NUM_LINES=(wc -l < "${P}")
```

but I'm always getting this error:

```
bash: house: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

Comment: It's not  `NUM_LINES=(wc -l < "${P}")` but rather `NUM_LINES=$(wc -l < "${P}")` Also no need to capitalize the var name and just simply `"$P"`

Comment: Also, you don’t need the `export` for the code you’ve shown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run a subshell use `$(...)` in bash. And you don't need to redirect the input, but simply name the input file. So omit the `<`:

```
NUM_LINES=$(wc -l "$P")
```

Output:

```
3 three_little_pigs.csv
```

To get rid of the filename, one possibility (there are many others) is to use awk:

```
NUM_LINES=$(wc -l "$P" | awk '{print $1}')
```

**EDIT 1:**

OK, using redirection (`<`) will omit the filename at all ... sorry ;)

```
NUM_LINES=$(wc -l < "$P")
```

Comment: Note that with some `wc` implementations, after `NUM_LINES=$(wc -l < "$P")`, `$NUM_LINES` will contain leading blanks. To discard them, a common trick is to use arithmetic expansion: `NUM_LINES=$(($(wc -l "$P")))`. That would also convert an empty output (like when the file can't be open) to `0`.

Comment: With some shells, like AT&T `ksh` or `zsh` (and assuming the default value of `$IFS`, one can also do `wc -l < "$P" | read num_lines` instead to get rid of those blanks.

Comment: Another advantage of `wc -l < "$P"` over `wc -l "$P"` is that it would work for files whose name starts with `-`. With some `wc` implementations like GNU `wc`, it's also better than `wc -l -- "$P"` as it works for a file called `-`.

Comment: Great! Didn't know about arithmetic expansion! Helpful!! Will continue reading about ...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But won't the `num_lines` shell variable be lost in the pipe-created subshell once `read` operation is complete? I mean, how does one get at the value in the `$num_lines` shell var.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, not in AT&T ksh or zsh that don't run that `read` in a subshell. See also the `lastpipe` option in `bash` (with restrictions) and `yash`.